# jqgrid aftersavefunc not called on SaveRow

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using onSelectRow method of jqGrid and calling aftersavefunc but this function does not execute when row is successfully saved, we are using clientarray to save data.

In jqgrid documentation it is written that it works with clientarray as well.

Code used is as below :-

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
            $('#grdTasks').jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel, true, 'clientArray', false, 
             { aftersavefunc: function () 
             {
                alert('saved');
             }
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set parameters with object:

```
saveparameters = {
    "successfunc" : null,
    "url" : 'clientArray',
    "extraparam" : {},
    "aftersavefunc" : function( response ) {
                          alert('saved');
                      },
    "errorfunc": null,
    "afterrestorefunc" : null,
    "restoreAfterError" : true,
    "mtype" : "POST"
}

$('#grdTasks').jqGrid('saveRow', rowid, saveparameters );
```